# How to redirect on register page if otp verified otherwise redirect to login Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, laravel-request

I am using Laravel 8 and Firebase to verify mobile with OTP. Now I want that if OTP verified then i can access register page if OTP is not verified then redirect to login page.
Now I am using default Laravel registration form and when OTP verified i stored in cookie. I have created middleware but its not work if cookie not set then also i access registration but i want it not accessable.
Middle-ware code is,

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Cookie::get('otpVerified')){
        return redirect()->route('register');
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Kernel code is,

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
    'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
    'otpVerify' =>  \App\Http\Middleware\OTPVarification::class,
];
```

web file is,

```
Route::get('language/{key}', [SwitchLanguageController::class,  'switchLanguage'])->name('language');


Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'showRegistrationForm'])->name('register')->middleware(['otpVerify']);

Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function (){

Route::get('/404', [\App\Http\Controllers\ErrorController::class, 'notFound'])->name('404');
Route::get('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
});
```

how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: you can crate `flash session`

Comment: Then how can i use it can you tell me more thanks.

Comment: add `otpVerified` route and controller so i can help with it

Answer (score 0):

The route you are defining in your `web.php` file that uses your `otpVerify` middleware is being overwritten by the `laravel/ui` package routes in `Auth::routes()`;

Check your routes using `php artisan route:list`.

You need to move your `register` route definition below `Auth::routes()`.

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'showRegistrationForm'])
    ->name('register')
    ->middleware(['otpVerify']);
```

Comment: How can i do that can you please explain more?

Comment: @IrshadKhan I have added an example to my answer.

Comment: This page isn’t workingwww.ereciept.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Getting this issue

Comment: Sounds like you're in a redirect look. Can you repost your `web.php` routes in your question?

Comment: Thanks i have done it. i have applied middleware in regsiter controller and change middleware coding like this

` if (Cookie::get('otpVerified')){
    return $next($request);
    }
        return redirect()->route('login');`