# How to solve redirect to undefiend route laravel?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

i am using Laravel 8 and I am using built in Auth module. I am login with mobile using ajax request. When user login and page redirct i get error /undefined route. I attach screen shoot of error.
[image]
My ajax code is,

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/login",
            headers:
                {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                },
            data: {
                'mobile' : user.phoneNumber
            },
            success: function (response){
                if (response.status === true){
                    // console.log('here')
                    // debugger
                    // window.location.reload();
                }
                window.location = response.url;
            }
        });
```

and my controller is, Here i check if user exist login it and reload if not exist then create new one and redirct to dashboard. If user not exist it working fine if user exist the i am facing issue

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    // Check validation
    $this->validate($request, [
        'mobile' => 'required|regex:/[0-9]{10}/',
    ]);

    // Get user record
    $user = User::where('mobile', $request->mobile)->first();

    if($user){
        // Check Condition Mobile No. Found or Not
        if($request->mobile != $user->mobile) {
            return response()->json(
                [
                    'status' => false,
                    'message' => 'Your mobile number not match in our system..!!'
                ], Response::HTTP_OK
            );
        }

        // Set Auth Details
        Auth::login($user);

        return \response()->json(
            [
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'Login Successfully'
            ], Response::HTTP_OK
        );
    }else{
        Cookie::queue('otpVerified', true);
        Session::put('mobile',$request->mobile);
        return response()->json(
            [
                'status' => false,
                'message' => 'User Not Exist',
                'url' => route('register')
            ], Response::HTTP_OK
        );
    }

}
```

my route file is,

```
Route::get('language/{key}', [SwitchLanguageController::class, 'switchLanguage'])->name('language');


Route::get('register', [RegisterController::class, 'showRegistrationForm'])->name('register')->middleware(['otpVerify']);

Auth::routes();
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function (){
Route::get('/404', [\App\Http\Controllers\ErrorController::class, 'notFound'])->name('404');
Route::get('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
});
```

How can i solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to send url after successfully login

```php
 return \response()->json(
            [
                'status' => true,
                'message' => 'Login Successfully'
                'url' => url('/') // add this whatever you want
            ], Response::HTTP_OK
        );
```

and in java script add one check

```js
if (response.url){
   window.location = response.url;                    
}
```

Comment: Thank you soo much you save my day. Its work fine

Comment: Can you help me on this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65503121/how-to-redirect-on-register-page-if-otp-verified-otherwise-redirect-to-login-lar